# I can not connect redis pod to webapp pod

Tags: kubernetes, redis

Here are logs of webapp pod

> {"date":"Mon Oct 09 2023 11:50:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard
> Time)","process":{"pid":1,"uid":0,"gid":0,"cwd":"/sails","execPath":"/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/node","version":"v14.17.1","argv":["/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/node","/sails/app.js","--prod","--port","8080"],"memoryUsage":{"rss":255209472,"heapTotal":187183104,"heapUsed":154731976,"external":78028716,"arrayBuffers":76383815}},"os":{"loadavg":[0.65,0.25,0.18],"uptime":2744194.54},"trace":[{"column":24,"file":"/sails/node_modules/redis/index.js","function":"RedisClient.on_error","line":196,"method":"on_error","native":false},{"column":14,"file":"/sails/node_modules/redis/index.js","function":null,"line":106,"method":null,"native":false},{"column":28,"file":"events.js","function":"Socket.emit","line":375,"method":"emit","native":false},{"column":12,"file":"domain.js","function":"Socket.emit","line":470,"method":"emit","native":false},{"column":8,"file":"internal/streams/destroy.js","function":"emitErrorNT","line":106,"method":null,"native":false},{"column":3,"file":"internal/streams/destroy.js","function":"emitErrorCloseNT","line":74,"method":null,"native":false},{"column":21,"file":"internal/process/task_queues.js","function":"processTicksAndRejections","line":82,"method":null,"native":false}],"stack":["Error:
> Redis connection to pv-redis:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> pv-redis","    at RedisClient.on_error
> (/sails/node_modules/redis/index.js:196:24)","    at
> Socket. (/sails/node_modules/redis/index.js:106:14)","
> at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)","    at Socket.emit
> (domain.js:470:12)","    at emitErrorNT
> (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)","    at emitErrorCloseNT
> (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)","    at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)"],"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException:
> Redis connection to pv-redis:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> pv-redis","timestamp":"Mon Oct 09 2023 11:50:54"}

Redis pod should connect Webapp pod
here is my redis pod yaml

```
# redis-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
---
# redis-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
```

and this is webapp yaml file

```
# webapp-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webapp
          image: 849324552297.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/pv-webapp
          env:
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: "redis"
            - name: REDIS_PORT
              value: "6379"
```

Comment: Please format your question, this is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

`"Error: Redis connection to pv-redis:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND pv-redis"`

Above error log indicates that the `webapp` pod is trying to connect to wrong redish service name `pv-redis`.

Solution:

Change the `redis` service name to `pv-redis`

```html
# redis-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pv-redis
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
```